# Android BroadcastReceiver, getResultData() always return null

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, battery

I am a novice to android and java development. Currently, I got a small task for **informing battery information as widget**.

I had searched around and found out a piece of source code for retrieve information from battery (http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html). I tried to adapt it to widget but I had a problem regarding to **BroadcastReceiver**. 
I tried to pass the value of level of battery from BroadcastReceiver to RemoteViews. I found method of getResultData() for BroadcastReceiver object but I always get Null value for it.

Therefore, I would like a suggestion to pass this BroadcastReceiver value to RemoteViews.

In order to make it clearer, I add piece of my code here.

```
public class MyBattery extends TimerTask {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetmanager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    TextView contentTxt; 

    Context context;
    public MyBattery(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager){
        this.appWidgetmanager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,widgetTest.class);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent){
            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);

            contentTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level)+"%");
            this.setResultData(String.valueOf(level)+"%");
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void run() {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery_label,""+ this.mBatInfoReceiver.getResultData());
        appWidgetmanager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this tutorial as it will help you in building your concept over BraodCastReceiver:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but the example here using broadcastReceiver with Activity. For me, I try to use it with widget.

Comment: I figured it out now. Thanks a lot!